# Can you create files in C with #define macro?

Tags: c, linux

I am looking at a line in a C-header file that I have not seen before:

```
#define var_name1 "/dev/node_file"
```

Is this line creating the file in /dev/ called *node_file*? Or is it just placing a variable name to the already existing *node_file*?

Comment: It's just defining a macro that expands to a string. Look for the code that uses the macro.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/constants/create_define.php

Comment: It does not do any of the things you ask. A `#define` directive defines a replacement. Everywhere in the code where you use `var_name1` it is replaced with `"/dev/node_file"`. The replacement happens on the pre-processing phase, before the actual code compilation.

Comment: What makes this different from any other `#define` you've seen before?

Comment: It is defining `var_name1` symbol to the string `"/dev/node_file"`. Each occourrence of the symbol `var_name1` in the translation unit will be replaced by the string `"/dev/node_file"` in preprocess phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axiac and Frankie_C have summed up the explanation for me: Everywhere in the code where `var_name1` is used, it will be replaced with `/dev/node_file`.

Comment: No, `var_name1` will be replaced by `"/dev/node_file"`, not by `dev/node_file`.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Postpischil

Comment: Just to be sure - it will be replaced by `"/dev/node_file"`. Including the two `"`.